# hibernate, server specific configuration

Tags: database, hibernate, configuration, connection

we have two different environments (test and production), each with it's own database connection.

The database connection is configured in the hibernate.cfg.xml, together with the mappings etc.
The hibernate.cfg.xml is part of the application - hence we cannot configure the database connection depending on the environment.

So we need some kind of configuration outside the application.

What is the best way for handling server specific database configurations with hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can configure using annotations. below is exa

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                    .addPackage("test.animals") //the fully qualified package name
                    .addAnnotatedClass(Flight.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(Sky.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(Person.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(Dog.class)
                    .addResource("test/animals/orm.xml")
                    .configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: But then I have source code which is specialized for a specific server. But I don't like to have server specific configuration in my sourcode.
 I thought of an external configuration, which is not part of the application